# How to analyze which permissions are needed by an .net assembly

Tags: .net-4.0, code-access-security

I need to know which permissions are requested by an assembly. With permission I mean for example the [WebPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webpermission.aspx)

Background: I have a service which executes plugins in a sandbox. These plugins are restricted with code-access security. For example: they aren't allowed to access the file system or the registry. Networking is restricted to only http, ...

I would like to analyze these plugins in our build-process to ensure that only classes are used, which are covered by the granted permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 2.0 through 3.5, the permcalc tool would have allowed you to extract a "best guess" minimum permission set for an assembly.  However, the tool has not been updated for .NET 4.0 where, for example, the new transparency approach would have a considerable impact on the analysis results.

AFAIK, there is no permcalc substitute (Microsoft or third-party, commercial or free) available for .NET 4.0.  In the absence of such a tool, your best bet for verifying the plug-ins would probably be an appropriate set of integration tests run under the runtime permission set.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with permcalc. I think I will create a test sandbox which replicates the production environment and test the plugins with it.